# MySQL Group Identical titles (row) and sum the money(row) but keep individual timestamp for sorting

Tags: php, mysql

I have been all over the internet to find answer for this, but I can't find any. (I might be asking incorrectly?)
I have a table which looks like this: 
[image]
I have been using the query:

```
SELECT title, date, SUM(money) 
FROM payments 
WHERE username = '$username_n' and type=0 
GROUP BY title
```

It does the trick, and it groups the identical titles and sum up their values

[image]

But as you can see, it only gives me ONE date, and I would like to be able to make a slider, where I can sort the date from the date, but I can't do that if it creates only one date for each grouped title.

How can I create multiple dates, but still get rid of the duplicated titles?

Comment: `GROUP BY title, date`

Comment: Please show desired results. Do you want one result line per title, per title and date, per title and datetime or what else? It would help to see sample results.

Comment: I made a mindmap to explain what I wish to accomplish
http://i.imgur.com/Mlgwo9A.png @ThorstenKettner

Comment: It seems you are interested in the individual records (the datetimes). So read them. Don't group by title, because you don't only want aggregated data per title (e.g. min or max datetime). Retrieve the single records and do whatever you want to do with the data (e.g. sum the money per title and) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT title, date, SUM(money) FROM payments 
WHERE username = '$username_n' and type=0 GROUP BY title, date(`date`);
```

Comment: How would I then output it so It can be sorted?

Comment: add `order by date` just after the `GROUP BY title, date(`date`)`

Answer (score 0):

It is a little weird with fields in the field list that are not aggregated or part of the grouping. As you had before with the date field:

```
SELECT title, date, SUM(money) FROM payments 
WHERE username = '$username_n' and type=0 
GROUP BY title
```

You group by title, and aggregate the money field, all good. The date field is not part of grouping or aggregation. What mysql is doing, it will just take the field value for the date field in the aggregation. Thats why you only see one date value in your result. As code-monk explained you need to use date field in the grouping. In MS SQL Server your query would actually error our, as MS SQL Server doesnt allow fields that are not part of grouping or aggregated, which I think is very good.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I don't think that would give be what I want to get. http://i.imgur.com/Mlgwo9A.png
@bdifferent This is what I mean :v

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give date values in comma separated manner. You can use PHP/server side code to explode those by comma and create a list/array and return it to client side i.e. JavaScript. Use javascript to sort the list.

```
SELECT title, group_concat(date) as `dates`, SUM(money) 
FROM payments 
WHERE username = '$username_n' and type=0 
GROUP BY title
```